# Comma inside for loop in rshiny ui

Tags: r, for-loop, user-interface, shiny

I need to call the same ui module multiple times inside shiny app ui. It needs to apply comma between the calling function. Applying for loop doesn't solve the issue as for loop does not work with comma inside. Please suggest a solution.

````
  for (1 in 1:length(Nifty221$Portfolio)){
    uiPort(i, Nifty221)
  }
  # uiPort(1, Nifty221),
  # uiPort(2, Nifty221)
  
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) ```
````

Comment: Try `lapply` instead of `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two parts. First, you will need do invoke the module UI for different input values and collect the returned tags in a list

```r
ui_list <- lapply(seq_along(Nifty221$Portfolio), function(i) {
  uiPort(i, Nifty221)
})
```

Now you can combine the list elements by wrapping a container around them. The easiest option is `htmltools::tagList()`

```r
ui_container_filled <- do.call(tagList, ui_list)
```

Then you can insert the `ui_container_filled` element anywhere in your ui. Wth the new features from R 4.1, this can also be written as follows

```r
ui_container_filled <- Nifty221$Portfolio |>
  seq_along() |>
  (\(i) => uiPort(i, Nifty221)) |>
  do.call(what = tagList)
```